# RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder method not calling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Below are my `ShelflifeAdapter` and `HomeFragment` classes:-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView shelflifeRecyclerview;
ShelflifeAdapter shelflifeAdapter;
Product product;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    shelflifeRecyclerview = rootView.findViewById(R.id.shelflifeRecyclerview);

    shelflifeAdapter = new ShelflifeAdapter(getContext());

    shelflifeRecyclerview.setAdapter(shelflifeAdapter);
    shelflifeRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    shelflifeRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //fragment->fragment 데이터받기
    Bundle bundle = getArguments(); //번들 받기
    if(bundle != null){
        product = new Product();
        product = (Product) bundle.getSerializable("bundle");
        shelflifeAdapter.addItem(product);
        Log.d("TAG", shelflifeAdapter.getItemCount() +" 갯수");
    }




    return rootView;
}
```

}

---

```
public class ShelflifeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShelflifeAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<Product> items = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Context mContext;

    ShelflifeAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("TAG","onCreateViewHolder 작동함");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_shelflife,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Log.d("TAG","onBindViewHolder 작동함");
        Product item = items.get(position);
        viewHolder.setItem(item,mContext);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public void addItem(Product item){

        if(item != null){
            Log.d("TAG","addItem 작동함(item 추가) : " + item.toString());
            items.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            Log.d("TAG","addItem 작동함(item 못가져옴)");
        }

    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Product> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Product getItem(int position){
        return items.get(position);
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView tv_shelflife;
        LinearLayout itemContainer;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            tv_shelflife = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shelflife);
            itemContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemContainer);
        }

        public void setItem(Product item, Context context){
            if(item != null){

                Log.d("TAG","어댑터의 item : "+ item.toString());

                if(item.getImage()==null){
                    Glide.with(itemView).load(R.drawable.no_image).override(48,48).into(imageView);
                }else{
                    Glide.with(itemView).load(item.image).override(48,48).into(imageView);
                }

                tv_shelflife.setText(item.shelflifeDate);

            }else{
                Log.d("TAG","item이 null임" );
            }


        }
    }
}
```

---

`addItem(Product item)` is working well
But  `onCreateViewHolder` method is not working.
Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: Log.d("TAG","어댑터의 item : "+ item.toString()); has value?

Comment: sorry this Log is not working..

Comment: because item is null that's why you can not get into if(item != null){}

Comment: Does the `onCreateView()` of the `HomeFragment` get called?

Comment: yes onCreateView() of the HomeFragment is working..

Comment: Log.d("TAG","addItem 작동함(item 추가) : " + item.toString()); of addItem method => working  // Log.d("TAG","어댑터의 item : "+ item.toString()); of setItem method => No working..

Comment: I might sound stupid but are you sure that your recycler view has a positive height? For example a wrong constraint cause it to have a 0 height.

Comment: my height of recycler view is wrap content..

Answer (score -1):

initialize recycler view first ,then set adapter for recycler view.

```
     shelflifeAdapter = new ShelflifeAdapter(getContext());
      
        shelflifeRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        shelflifeRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
//Always set adapter after  setLayoutManager, setHasFixedSize 
 shelflifeRecyclerview.setAdapter(shelflifeAdapter);

 Bundle bundle = getArguments(); //번들 받기
    if(bundle != null){
        product = new Product();
        product = (Product) bundle.getSerializable("bundle");
        
        shelflifeAdapter.addItem(product);
       
        Log.d("TAG", shelflifeAdapter.getItemCount() +" 갯수");
    }
```

And make sure item is not null

```
 Product item = items.get(position);
  if(item!=null)
    viewHolder.setItem(item,mContext);
```

pass context into glide

```
if(item.getImage()==null){
                Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.no_image).override(48,48).into(imageView);
            }else{
                Glide.with(context).load(item.image).override(48,48).into(imageView);
            }

            tv_shelflife.setText(item.shelflifeDate);
```

Comment: THat shouldn't be necessary.  Calling notifyDataSetChanged is enough to tell the adapter to redisplay with new items.  You don't need to set the adapter after setting the items.

Comment: He  is getting value from bundle and he is trying to put that value in recycler view.before bundle he did not add anything to his object.That's why i said, call adapter  after initialize.@GabeSechan

Comment: His addItem function calls notifyDataSetChanged, which is sufficient to get the adapter to redraw the RecyclerView from scratch.  His problem is that the item in the Bundle is null, which is why his comment above says that a log wasn't working as well.  You don't have to wait for data to set the adapter.  In fact you normally don't, you generally set that at the top and load data when its available (which may be after a network call).

Comment: Please read the question's last line he said (addItem(Product item) is working well But onCreateViewHolder method is not working).addItem() method has if(item != null).from that we can understand ,bundle item is not null And he called setAdapter before initialize recyclerview , that's is only the main issue.@GabeSechan

Comment: Read his comments, he said the log line that runs if item!= null isn't firing.  And your solution wouldn't actually fix anything, as calling notifyDatasetChanged will reset the adapter, making it unnecessary to set the adapter after loading data.  Its very unusual to actually have all the data in fragment create, its normal to set the adapter there and load data later.  You just have to call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Basically, even if I'm off on the item being null in the Bundle (a possibility), your answer is also wrong.  Because you don't need to set the adapter later if notifyDataSetChanged is called, which it is.

Comment: Yes you are correct ,my intention was when i write solution ,he called setAdapter before  setLayoutManager, setHasFixedSize methods.that won't work.he need to call after that methods.That was my only intention ,i did not notice notifyDataSetChanged within addItem() and now updated my answer.Thanks.@GabeSechan